# Is there a consumer level handwriting synthesis engine?

Tags: computer-vision, image-recognition, neural-network

A number of [papers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.0850) have been written on handwriting synthesis using techniques such as computer vision and neural networks. Can anyone recommend any software (including reusable code) which can synthesize my own handwriting?

For clarity, I am not solely looking for handwriting recognition; the software should be able to reproduce my own handwriting by learning how I write via stylus input or analysis of scanned documents.

Answer (score 1):

The Visual Computing department at UCL have published their work in this field. A github repository containing usable code can be found here:

https://github.com/thaines/helit/tree/master/handwriting